# class with argument and variable in Dart save to Firebase at wrong fields

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm into Dart/Flutter development, I'm slowly catching few things that's really weird.

Let's say

```
class Person{
 final String name;
 final String age;
 final String address;
    Person({this.name, this.address,this.age});
}
```

Then I tried to use this class and pass arguments onto the class.

```
person = Person(name:"killedVariableSwitch", age:"1024", address:"Mars");
```

So I use the above class to save it in someother database or any class that requires the above implementation. Drastically fails to order itself. My previous code with other programs corrects itself as I remember.

You can notice that, I switched age and address position in that argument. Now the database holds the key:value pair is wrong.

```
print(person.fromDatabase);

name: killedVariableSwitch, address:1024, age:Mars.
```

Is this desired output or it should correct itself?. I never experienced this previous android or java.
Or I'm doing something wrong here.

More example shot from my doing.

[image]

After saving in Firebase Cloudfirestore

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: you are just failing to save/write to the DB correctly, named parameters in dart doesn't need to be as ordered as in the constructor

Comment: try to maintain correct sequence of fields in your model class as same as your api response.\

Comment: But i guess this happened a lot to me i guess, Or i didnt cared about the named parameters. Is there any document about the passing parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Indeed that's the cause, If I place the order different in main class, Then the passing arguments have real side effects!.

Dart need to fix this I guess. Or I'm doing totally wrong!!!

```
@JsonSerializable()
class User extends Equatable {
 final String id;
 final String name;
 final String mobileNo;
 final String email;
 final String picture;
 final String dateCreated;
 final String fcmTokenId;

const User(
  {this.id,
  this.name,
  this.mobileNo,
  this.email,
  this.picture,
  this.dateCreated,
  this.fcmTokenId});
```

The onpress call

```
context.read<HomeBloc>().add(AddUser(User(
            name: "NoName",
            dateCreated:DateTime.now().toString(),
            email: "s.puspahraj.com",
            fcmTokenId: "dddadasda",
            picture: "ddsf",
            mobileNo:  _user.mobileNo)))



 @JsonSerializable()
 class UserEntity extends Equatable {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String mobileNo;
  final String email;
  final String picture;
  final String dateCreated;
  final String fcmTokenId;
```

Mixed up here!!!!

```
 Map<String, Object> toDocument() {
  return {
  "id": id,
  "name": name,
  "dateCreated": dateCreated,
  "email": email,
  "picture": picture,
  "mobileNo": mobileNo,
  "fcmTokenId": fcmTokenId
   };
  ***************************** 
 @override
  Future<void> addUser(User user) {
   return usersCollection
    .add(user.toEntity().toDocument())
    .then((value) => _logger.d('user added'))
    .catchError((error) => _logger.e("Failed to add user: $error"));
```

So I have to be really careful while placing those arguments!